# ICC pin encipherment (VISA)

Tags: java, android, smartcard, open-mobile-api

I'm accessing the smartcard via OpenMobileAPI.

I successfully read the PAN (hidden values of course) using the **GetProtectedData (80 D8 01 00 00)**, by getting the **modulus (80 CA DF 07 00)** / **exponent(80 CA DF 05 00)** value, and creating the public key and so on.

Now I need to read `visible data` (complete pan number, expiry date, ..).

I know I need to do a **VerifyPasscode**. 
I created the `public key` by **modulus/exponent (same as before)**, and enciphered the pin data using RSA (**7F + pin block + unpredictable number + padding**), and sent it using the **VerifyPasscode command (00 20)**. but I get the response as **(69 84: Referenced data reversibly blocked (invalidated)).**

so I believe my encpipherment is not correct.

any ideas ?

Thank you